# Changing a function in a compiled language for numerical simulation

Tags: c, compilation

I want to numerically simulate an evolution equation with a compiled language (say C). This evolution equation depends on a pre-defined function f(x) that takes a double as an input and spits another double (some sort of R -> R function).

The bulk of my code is in the numerical method, while the f(x) function is a two-line thing.

If I want to change this function f(x) often and change it to something arbitrary (as opposed to just changing a parameter which I can read from a file), what is my best option? Putting this function in a separate file and recompiling and linking only this file every time? Is there any other solution I am not seeing at the moment?

Comment: Are you looking for an _expression evaluator_ (google that term) ? Putting the function in a separate file and recompiling and linking is an easy option, but it may not be suitable for your use case, which you didn't specifiy.

Comment: Yes, putting each function in a single translation unit and linking it seems like a good option. Another one, more complicated, is to integrate a script language (lua, python, etc.) to implement the numerical function.

Comment: @Jabberwocky is there such a thing in compiled languages?

Comment: @nabla there are libraries, and a lot of source code. Google is your friend.

Comment: @Ctx I thought of that. However (although I didn't specify this in the question), I fear using Python for this part might result in a decrease in performance.

Comment: @nabla You can easily compare the performance by re-implementing a function, that you already use, in python and run it a few thousand times with both methods and compare the results. It will be slower, but probably not relevant.